# Unable to receive UDP packets

Tags: networking, server, python, iptables, firewall

I am trying to send UDP packets from Network Simulator 3 (NS-3) to a Multi-threaded python server(Using UDP socket) but I am unable to receive the packet on the server-side. From the host machine, I am able to receive the UDP packets using the Netcat tool.

Both NS3 and Python Server are running on the same machine.

I am able to ping the server from the NS3 node(device).

Can you please help what can be the issue? why the packets are not reaching the server in this scenario?

Comment: Verify on the server side at which address and what port its UDP socket is listening. `sudo netstat -lnup`  Does the values agree with address/port where the client connects?

Comment: I checked using the command and it's correct where the client connects.
server is listening at 10.0.0.1:5566 as configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem may be that if both the source and the receiver of the packets are on the same machine, they do not actually communicate with each other through the address of the external interface (10.0.0.1), but through loopback 127.0.0.1. Therefore, for example, a different filter rule or set of policies in the firewall may apply.

It is necessary to inspect the network communication using the analyzer.

You can practically try it out with the Wireshark app. Find out the names of both interface first:

```
ip addr
```

I will assume they are `eth0` and `lo`.
Run Wireshark and capture packets first on the `eth0` interface and then on `lo`. In both cases use the display filter `icmp` to display only ping packets in Wireshark. And use the `udp.port==5566` display filter to capture the UDP packets during attempts with the UDP.

I bet that even if you ping the IP address 10.0.0.1, you will not catch ICMP packets on the `eth0` interface, but on `lo`. That's how it works on all my computers.

Then check what the situation looks like using UDP tests.

Try using 127.0.0.1 as the destination address instead of 10.0.0.1.

Another problem is that some applications such as `netcat` do not have a visible listening UDP socket when checked using netstat.

If you run two netcat instances listening on the same UDP port on the same machine, no error is reported, but only one netcat application actually receives the data. Here may be another source of the problem: an "invisible" port collision.

Use Wireshark and you will see if packets are being sent and received.

I hope this sheds light on the solution to the problem.

Comment: I added the firewall rule and it's working. It seems like the firewall was not letting the packets through.